# Electron and TypeScript: 'fs' can't be resolved

Tags: typescript, webpack, electron

I'm trying to create my first Electron app. I've decided to use following tools/technologies:

- TypeScript
- WebPack (version 3)
- React

Local environment is OS X High Sierra.

The problem is that I can't even build my app and I get error on building with WebPack: "`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '<root>/node_modules/electron'` "

I have configuration given below:
package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.7.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.ts',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    // node: {
    //     'fs': 'empty'
    // },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
};
```

Finally, my only source code file (`./src/index.ts`) taken from electron tutorial looks like:

```
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as url from 'url';

let win: Electron.BrowserWindow;

function createWindow () {
    // ... common stuff
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
app.on('window-all-closed', () => { if (process.platform !== 'darwin') { app.quit(); }});
app.on('activate', () => { if (win === null) { createWindow(); }});
```

I assume that the problem is in the way of TypeScript usage because if I put such code from index.ts to the plain js file, it works correctly (replacing 'import' with 'require').

Thanks for any help in advance!

**Update**

If set `{ target: 'node', }` in `webpack.config.js` then there is no error on building step, but if I try to open app I get:

```
App threw an error during load
Error: Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again
```

reinstalling of node modules doesn't help.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Ok, finally I've found the solution worked for me. The 'target' option should be defined in `webpack.config.js`. And it shouldn't be `{ target: 'node' }`, as I tried before

As it appears, Webpack has specific target settings for electron apps, therefore the correct way is to set it:

```
{
    // for files that should be compiled for electron main process
    target: 'electron-main'
}
```

or

```
{
    // for files that should be compiled for electron renderer process
    target: 'electron-renderer'
}
```

That's it. Just need to read docs carefully :- (

Comment: For some reason this isn't working for me; there's a level of indirection in my webpack config in that I went via `create-react-app` & use `rescripts` to specify WebPack target. However, I'm sure that the target is properly set yet I still fail to resolve `fs` etc.

Comment: do you find solution?

Comment: (node:58842) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The "target" property is no longer supported in next.config.js.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the original answer. If you are using Electron + Next.js, you need to specify the `target` in `next.config.js` file. If you do not have one, create it on the root level of your app (where `package.json` is located). Add the following:

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    if (!isServer) {
      config.target = "electron-renderer";
    }
    return config;
  },
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I came across this on a search and I'd offer an improve answer for dealing with errors that only happen on certain build targets:

```
const config = {
    //basic module.exports rules here
}

module.exports = [
    config,
    {
        ...config,
        target: 'web', //target that needs special rules, then all your other special config rules in this object
        node: {
            fs: 'empty'
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    externals: {
      './cptable': 'var cptable'
    },
    resolve: {
      fallback: {
        'fs': false,
        'crypto': false
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Feel like I should add an additional answer for anyone who isn't helped by the other answers. I've spent a while attempting to update an older Electron project to new module builds whilst also implementing Typescript and I kept being hit by the:

```
[0] ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js 1:11-24
[0] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '<root_dir>/node_modules/electron'
```

and...

```
[0] ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js 3:13-28
[0] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '<root_dir>/node_modules/electron'
```

After a lot of misery and a sh*t tonne of commenting out I finally found that the culprit was a `require("electron")` statement. I changed this to be `window.require("electron")` and it sprang to life!

So I hope that helps someone else (or future me)!

Comment: in renderer/pages/index.tsx I get error: `Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: window.require is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes adding `nodeIntegration:true` in `webPreferences` for mainWindow could solve the problem.